# OpenCV: File Size of H.264 encoded videos

Tags: c++, opencv, video, h.264, x264

I write a program that creates a video file out of an image sequence using OpenCV. It runs fine and does what it should, but I realized something I can't explain. My Videowriter looks like this:

```
VideoWriter video(name + ".avi", CV_FOURCC(FOURCC[0], FOURCC[1], FOURCC[2], FOURCC[3]), fps, cvSize((int)width, (int)height));

    for (;;)
    {
        capture >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;
        if (!frame.data)
        {
            cerr << "Could not retrieve frame.";
            return -1;
        }
        video << frame;
    }
```

For compression, I use either "MJPG", "M4S2" (some MPEG-4 codec) or "X264" (a H.264 codec). I'm getting the "fps" value by user input. Everything works fine, but I found that the output file of X264 encoded videos scales with the fps, the higher the fps the smaller the output file. For the other 2 the size remains the same, just the length of the video changes (as I would expect since it should have the same number of frames, just in another amount of time).
Can anyone explain me why the file size changes using X264 here?

Comment: I'm not so experienced in encoding, but first intuition: maybe bitrate stays the same so you use same bits per time => less time = less bits used?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is kind of late, i figured it out...it seems it was just a bug of OpenCV. When I used the OpenCV method to use the h.264 encoder, the video file was corrupted. When I used FFmpeg instead everything worked fine.